# override create method with multiple returns in OpenERP ver 7

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need to do two activities in my activity method.
one is need to return value for total_workers field.but need to return ID also because its necessary requirement in OpenERP when we override that method.
then have to return 2 things.please advice me how to implement this in my form.
with one return value this is worked for both things.but need to return both.

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
    name = 'CheckRoll No = ' + str(values['checkroll_no']) + ' & Gang No = ' + str(values['gang_no'])
    values.update({'name': name})
    total_tea_workers = 0
    offer_id = super(bpl_work_offer, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
    tea_worker_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, offer_id, context=context) or []
    tea_worker_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.selected.tea.workers.line').search(cr, uid, [('tea_line_worker_id', '=', tea_worker_obj.id)])
    for tea_worker in self.pool.get('bpl.selected.tea.workers.line').browse(cr, uid, tea_worker_ids):
        if tea_worker.is_selected:
            total_tea_workers += 1
    return {'value': {'total_workers': total_tea_workers}}
    return offer_id
```

**EDITED**

I sort it out in this way.hope this will help for others
:-)

> ***i wrote a function for my field***

```
def _compute_workers(self, cr, uid, ids, fieldname, arg, context=None):
    total_workers = total_tea_workers = total_rubber_workers = total_sundry_workers = total_other_workers = 0
    res = dict.fromkeys(ids, False) 
    for this in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        tea_worker_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.selected.tea.workers.line').search(cr, uid, [('tea_line_worker_id', '=', this.id)])
        for tea_worker in self.pool.get('bpl.selected.tea.workers.line').browse(cr, uid, tea_worker_ids):
            if tea_worker.is_selected:
                total_tea_workers += 1                
        rubber_worker_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.selected.rubber.workers.line').search(cr, uid, [('rubber_line_worker_id', '=', this.id)])
        for rubber_worker in self.pool.get('bpl.selected.rubber.workers.line').browse(cr, uid, rubber_worker_ids):
            if rubber_worker.is_selected:
                total_rubber_workers += 1                
        sundry_worker_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.selected.sundry.workers.line').search(cr, uid, [('sundry_line_worker_id', '=', this.id)])
        for sundry_worker in self.pool.get('bpl.selected.sundry.workers.line').browse(cr, uid, sundry_worker_ids):
            if sundry_worker.is_selected:
                total_sundry_workers += 1                
        other_worker_ids = self.pool.get('bpl.selected.other.workers.line').search(cr, uid, [('other_line_worker_id', '=', this.id)])
        for other_worker in self.pool.get('bpl.selected.other.workers.line').browse(cr, uid, other_worker_ids):
            if other_worker.is_selected:
                total_other_workers += 1
    total_workers = total_tea_workers + total_rubber_workers + total_sundry_workers + total_other_workers                                                                             
    res[this.id] = total_workers 
    return res
```

> ***i changed my integer field to functional field***

'total_workers': fields.function(_compute_workers, type="integer", string="Total Workers"),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never return anything else in `create()` except the ID of the record that was created. Usually this is done by returning the result of the call to the parent via `super(myclass, self).create(...)` indeed.

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with your `total_workers` code. If `total_workers` is supposed to be a computed field, you don't have to override `create` at all: just declare this column as a [`fields.function`](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/03_module_dev_02/#functional-fields) and put the code to compute it in the corresponding function.

For example:

```
def _compute_workers(self, cr, uid, ids, fieldname, arg, context=None):
    result = dict.fromkeys(ids, False) # default result for each id
    for this in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        # let's assume you have a one2many called worker_ids
        result[this.id] = len(this.worker_ids)
    return result

_columns = {
    'total_workers': fields.function(_compute_workers, type="integer",
                                     string="Total Workers")
}
```

At this point it would be a good idea to have a good look at the [OpenERP technical memento](http://doc.openerp.com/memento/) and the [OpenERP framework documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/), to get an overview of the OpenERP API and how it is supposed to be used :-)

Once you have a good understanding of the structure of models, the various field types, the CRUD methods and the inheritance patterns, you should be able to quickly browse the source code of the official modules and find examples of anything you want to accomplish. This should make your life much more easier!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're doing the counting of the workers in a very inefficient manner.
You're doing your SQL filter to obtain each of the workers matching an ID, and then testing for a single flag within them.

I think it would be much more efficient to just add another criteria to your select statement.

```
total_tea_workers = self.pool.get('bpl.selected.tea.workers.line').search(cr, uid, [('tea_line_worker_id', '=', id), ('is_selected', '=', True)]), count=True)
```